# Как при связке 3 таблиц SQL выполнить WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
    SELECT s_products.name, s_categories.id, s_products_categories.product_id, s_products_categories.category_id
FROM s_products 

LEFT JOIN s_products_categories ON s_products.id = s_products_categories.product_id
LEFT JOIN s_categories ON s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id

ORDER BY s_categories.id
```

Как выполнить в этой объединённой таблице `WHERE s_categories.id = 7`

```
    name            | id | product_id | category_id

    Футболка Красная| 6  | 1213       | 6
    Футболка Синяя  | 7  | 1345       | 7
    Куртка          | 7  | 1270       | 7
```

Comment: а кто вам мешает в принципе просто дописать это условие `where` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, что ли?

```
SELECT s_products.name, s_categories.id, s_products_categories.product_id, s_products_categories.category_id
FROM s_products 
LEFT JOIN s_products_categories ON s_products.id = s_products_categories.product_id
LEFT JOIN s_categories ON s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id AND s_categories.id = 7 
ORDER BY s_categories.id
```

Или так?

```
SELECT s_products.name, s_categories.id, s_products_categories.product_id, s_products_categories.category_id
FROM s_products 
LEFT JOIN s_products_categories ON s_products.id = s_products_categories.product_id
LEFT JOIN s_categories ON s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id 
WHERE s_categories.id = 7 
ORDER BY s_categories.id
```

Плохо понятно, что же нужно...

Comment: Сработал 2 вариант так, как надо. Спасибо